# Can Cases associated with Contacts via Contact Roles display on the Cases related list on the Contact record?

Tags: related-list, contact, case

I have enabled the "Contact Role" related list on both Opportunities and Cases.

When I add a contact, and specify a role for an Opportunity, the corresponding related list on the Contact's record (Opportunities related list) links nicely back to the Opportunity.

This does not happen for Cases. That is, when I add a contact, and specify a role for a Case, the corresponding related list on the Contact's record (Cases related list) does not link back to the Case.

Can Cases associated with Contacts via Contact Roles display on the Cases related list on the Contact record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can think of to do this is to use Visualforce and to roll your own related list. Not what you want to hear, I bet.

Answer (score -1):

You need to enable Cases in the related list for Contacts in order to see what you're asking about on the Contact Record. You might also want to use the Contact (Support) Layout for your purposes as well, since it was designed for this specific purpose. You'll still need to enable Cases in the related list for this Layout if you want to choose which fields you want to see. There's also the option to enable Opportunities for this Layout as well.

> See the following screen shots from my DevOrg. First is the list of
>   Contact Layout pages:

[image]

> Next is the mini-page layout editor showing where I can add the Case
>   and Opportunity  related lists to the Contact (Support) Layout:

[image]

> Finally, you'll see that both the Cases and Opportunity related lists
>   can be added to the general Contact Layout Page via the mini
>   page-layout editor:

[image]

> I hope this provides you with all the details you need. It's entirely
>   possible that in some editions of SF (anything below Enterprise
>   Edition), that these options won't be available.

Comment: Not true. The Opportunities related list on Contact shows Contact Roles. The Cases related list on Contact shows Cases - where the Contact is the primary contact on the Case.

Comment: See the screen-shots I've added to my post above. If you've evidence to the contrary, I suggest you check your version of SF and post any documentation you have that supports your assertion.

Comment: The original question is, "Can Cases associated with Contacts via Contact Roles display on the Cases related list on the Contact record?" - none of your screenshots assert that this is possible. All you have done is show how to add related lists to page layouts and hover page layouts. You have not asserted that the DATA in the Contact Role related list includes all Cases for which the Contact is in a Contact Role. (Hint: It doesn't include that.)